# bluetooth connectivity with devices to devices

Tags: bluetooth

I want to know which device bluetooth is connected to which device

for example iphone 5 bluetooth connected with only iphone 5 bluetooth or can connected with other bluetooth like ipad, ipod or other iphone.

Comment: It is not clear what are you asking about. In general Bluetooth defines a generic protocol that allows any two devices to communicate with some restrictions applied in Apple products.

Comment: sorry about clearness of question. Suppose my iphone5 bluetooth connect with other device bluetooth (like iphone4, 4s, 5c, ipod etc) for transfer file etc. or we can only connect or transfer file betweet same devices like iphone 5 to iphone 5 only same ipad bluetooth to other ipad bluetooth in manner